# Cmake error while building gromacs (ubuntu 14.10 64 bit)

Tags: cmake

I installed `cmake` without any error in Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit

I am getting this error while running `cmake` in `gromacs` build directory

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/bin
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: How did you installed cmake?

Comment: @A.B  I used following commands tar xzvf cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz then cd cmake-3.2.2 then ./configure then make and then sudo make install

Comment: sorry m new to this so my replies may not be clearly formatted..

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615451/cmake-missing-modules-directory it says you just have to export the cmake root env variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Please compile `cmake` again* and use this `./configure` (The default value is `/usr/local`):

```
sudo make uninstall
make clean
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
```

And you should use `sudo checkinstall` and not `sudo make install` to get a `.deb` file:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

It may be that you first need to delete your old cmake installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
sudo apt-get remove cmake-data
```

and than install the compiled version with:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

That's all **=)**

Comment: Thank you for help.. I will get back to you after compiling

Comment: (Reading database ... 173178 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cmake_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cmake (3.2.2-1) over (2.8.12.2-0ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/rakesh/Downloads/cmake-3.2.2/cmake_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/aclocal/cmake.m4', which is also in package cmake-data 2.8.12.2-0ubuntu6
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/rakesh/Downloads/cmake-3.2.2/cmake_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb
(END)

Comment: I am getting this error in the log file after using sudo checkinstall

Comment: @RakeshPandit `sudo apt-get remove cmake` and than `sudo checkinstall`

Comment: @RakeshPandit does it work?

Comment: how can i remove cmake if installed manually and not from ubuntu software centre

Comment: Sorry, cmake-data, see my update

Comment: "A.B. how can i remove cmake-3.2.2 as i've installed it manually and not from the repository

Comment: make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'Utilities/cmcurl/lib/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/build'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1414: recipe for target 'Utilities/cmcurl/lib/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/lib/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK

Bye... I am getting this error with checkinstall

Comment: Did you after `make uninstall`, run `./configure --prefix=/usr` and `make`?

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/usr  gives following error  CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "cmcurl".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cmcurl
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rakesh/Downloads/cmake-3.2.2
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running initial CMake
---------------------------------------------

Comment: Run a `make clean` before configure. Or remove the folder cmake-3.2.2 folder and start with a new.